# Hotmail checker for Mac

Tags: mac, hotmail

I was wondering if there is a Hotmail checker that works on the Mac. I am looking for something that works like Google's Gmail checker, notifying you of an email soon after you receive it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Daniel’s HTTPMail Plug-in](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/email_chat/danielshttpmailplugin.html), which will allow you to check, read, and send email through Hotmail using Mail.app.

I can't remember if Mail.app provides its own pop-up notifications, but if it doesn't, you can use [Growl](http://growl.info/) to show the notifications (for Mail.app and a whole bunch of other stuff).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using POP or IMAP, I would recommend using Mail.app w/ the [GrowlMail](http://growl.info/documentation/growlmail.php) Plugin.

Comment: Hotmail (now known as Windows Live Mail) apparently only provides POP3 access to paying customers.

Comment: Well i dont need it with mail app, just a separate app which tell me if there is any new email or not